# belongs_to add a relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

these are my models

```
class Apartment
belongs_to :house
end

class House
has_many :apartments
end
```

apartment_controller;

```
def index
    @apartments = Appartment.all
end
```

apartment index view

```
.span9
  #container
    - @appartments.each do |apartment|
      .item{:class => apartment.features_to_html_class }
        %article.info.t_xs
          .article-base
            %section
              .span3
                %h2 #{link_to apartment.name, appartment_path(apartment)}
                %p 
                  = raw truncate(apartment.property_description, :length => 375, :omission => '...')
                %footer
                  %ul.meta
                    %li.comments
                      #{apartment.count_ratings} 
                      = t('apartment.details.reviews')
                    %li.notes
                      #{apartment.guests}
                      = t('apartment.details.persons')
                    %li.notes
                      #{apartment.bedrooms}
                      = t('apartment.details.bedrooms')
                    %li.notes
                      #{apartment.bathrooms}
                      = t('apartment.details.bathrooms')

            %ul.thumbnails
              %li.span5
                = image_tag(apartment.attachments.last.file.url, :class => 'thumbnail')
              - apartment.attachments.limit(4).each do |a|
                %li.span1
                  %a{:href => "#"}
                  = image_tag(a.file.url(:thumb), :class => "thumbnail")

            .span8
              %footer
                #more
                  #{link_to t('apartments.summary.button'), appartment_path(apartment), :class => 'btn btn-primary'}
```

i get all the apartments from the DB. But now i want to add a link (belongs_to) to the house in at the apartment summary. how can i do this...thanks..remco

Comment: Could you add the rake routes output?

Comment: Er, are you asking how to create an HTML hyperlink to house, or how to associate the apartment with the house with a foreign key relationship? I think you mean the latter, but some of the answers and questions here are assuming the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try 
   link_to 'House', house_path(apartment.house) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'House', house_path(apartment.house) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'House', house_url(apartment.house) %>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You got all the apartments in the database.
Now you run the sql to get the `apartments` object.
Then iterate each apartment and link it to house with the association.

**This is done as follows:**

```
def index
        @apartments = Appartment.all

    @apartments.each do |apartment|
       #this is giving you the link to house via association defined.
         apartment.house 

       #this is giving you the value of the field say `house_name` of house table that is linked to apartment.

         @house_name = apartment.house.house_name
      .
      .
      .
    end
end
```